# Is there an established pattern for SQL queries which group by a range?

Tags: sql, sql-server, design-patterns, group-by

I've seen a [lot of questions](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=group%20by%20a%20range%20in%20sql) on SO concerning how to group data by a range in a SQL query.

The exact scenarios vary, but the general underlying problem in each is to group by a range of values rather than each discrete value in the `GROUP BY` column. In other words, to group by a less precise granularity than you're storing in the database table.

This crops up often in the real world when producing things like histograms, calendar representations, pivot tables and other bespoke reporting outputs.

Some example data (tables unrelated):

```
|      OrderHistory       |       |         Staff        |                
---------------------------       ------------------------
|    Date    |  Quantity  |       |   Age     |   Name   |
---------------------------       ------------------------       
|01-Jul-2012 |     2      |       |    19     |   Barry  |
|02-Jul-2012 |     5      |       |    53     |   Nigel  |
|08-Jul-2012 |     1      |       |    29     |   Donna  |
|10-Jul-2012 |     3      |       |    26     |   James  |
|14-Jul-2012 |     4      |       |    44     |   Helen  |
|17-Jul-2012 |     2      |       |    49     |   Wendy  |
|28-Jul-2012 |     6      |       |    62     |   Terry  |
---------------------------       ------------------------
```

Now let's say we want to use the `Date` column of the `OrderHistory` table to group by weeks, i.e. 7-day ranges. Or perhaps group the `Staff` into 10-year age ranges:

```
|       Week      |  QtyCount  |        |  AgeGroup | NameCount |         
--------------------------------        -------------------------
|01-Jul to 07-Jul |     7      |        |   10-19   |    1      |
|08-Jul to 14-Jul |     8      |        |   20-29   |    2      | 
|15-Jul to 21-Jul |     2      |        |   30-39   |    0      |
|22-Jul to 28-Jul |     6      |        |   40-49   |    2      |
--------------------------------        |   50-59   |    1      |
                                        |   60-69   |    1      |
                                        -------------------------
```

`GROUP BY Date` and `GROUP BY Age` on their own won't do it.

The most common answers I see (none of which are consistently voted "correct") are to use one or more of:

- a bunch of `CASE` statements, one per grouping
- a bunch of `UNION` queries, with a different `WHERE` clause per grouping
- as I'm working with SQL Server, [`PIVOT()` and `UNPIVOT()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177410%28v=sql.105%29.aspx)
- a two-stage query using a sub-select, temp table or View construct

Is there an established generic pattern for dealing with such queries?

Comment: A CTE is often used to generate a table of ranges on-the-fly.  The result is then joined to the data being summarized.

Comment: For a number of reasons, you shouldn't store a derived value like 'age' - which, after all, will need to be updated every year, at some (potentially unknown) point during the year.  Much better to store `birthday` and calculate a person's age on the fly.

Comment: @X-Zero Indeed we do, this is just for example purposes to eliminate the step of calculating 'age' from 'birthday' (which is a question in itself!).

Comment: ... Because people are actually born at a particular instant in time, but it's usually referenced without the time information; people don't worry about time zones, they just deal with the 'observed' (solar) day.

Answer (score 3):

You can use some of the dimensional modeling techniques, such as [fact tables](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fact_table) and [dimension tables](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dimension_table). Order History can act as a fact table with DateKey foreign key relation to a Date dimension. 
Date dimension can have a schema such as below:

[image: Date Dimesion]

Note that Date table is pre-filled with data up-to N number of years.

Using an example above, here is a sample query to get the result:

```
select CalendarWeek, sum(Quantity)
from OrderHistory a
join DimDate b
    on a.DateKey = b.DateKey
group by CalendarWeek
```

For Staff table, you can store Birthday Key instead of age and let the query calculate the age and ranges.

Here is [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/deb80/3)

Date dimension population script was taken from [here](http://jsimonbi.wordpress.com/2011/10/09/populating-your-date-dimension/).

Answer (score 2):

As is often the case this SQL problem requires using more than one pattern in composition.

In this case the two you can use are

- NTILE
- Numbers Table

You can use [NTITLE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175126.aspx) to create a set number of groups. However since you don't have each member of the groups represented you also need to use a **numbers table** Since you're using SQL Server you have it easy as you don't have to simulate either.

Here's an example for the Staff problem

```
WITH g as (
SELECT 
     NTILE(6) OVER (ORDER BY number) grp, 
     NUMBER
FROM 
    master..spt_values
WHERE 
    TYPE = 'P'
and number >=10 and number <=69
)
SELECT 
      CAST(min(g.number) as varchar) + ' - ' + 
      CAST(max(g.number) as varchar) AgeGroup ,
      COUNT(s.age) NameCount
FROM 
     g
     LEFT JOIN Staff s
     ON g.NUMBER = s.Age
GROUP BY 
    grp
```

[DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/ff1f0/14)

You can apply this to dates as well it just requires some date to day maniplulation

Answer (score 1):

Couldn't you treat the age (or date) as a foreign key in a new, tiny table that is just ages (or dates) and their corresponding ranges?  A join statement could provide a new table with a column that contains AgeGroups.  With the new table you could use the standard group-by method.

It does seem reckless to make a new table for grouping, but it would be easy to make programatically and I think it would be easier to maintain (or drop and recreate) than a case statement or a where clause.  If the result of this query is a one-off, a throwaway sql statement would probably work best, but I think my method makes the most sense for long-term use.

Comment: That wouldn't be very convenient for the dates example, though - there's a lot of dates in the world! And what happens if we  later redefine a 'week' as starting on each Friday rather than the first day of the month?

Comment: Not so many dates in important period (1950-2050) - only 36500 :)

Comment: @DmitryOsinovskiy OK, fair point. Although I just have a feeling that whoever's maintaining my code in 2051 will have a millennium-bug style problem on their hands!

Comment: @Widor You can have a scheduled job that would automatically check that all days upto 10 (or 50) years in future are already in the table and would add missing dates. This is not that hard. We also did this.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the [OVER clause](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189461.aspx) and its associated clauses: PARTITION BY, ROW, RANGE...

> Determines the partitioning and ordering of a rowset before the
>   associated window function is applied. That is, the OVER clause
>   defines a window or user-specified set of rows within a query result
>   set. A window function then computes a value for each row in the
>   window. You can use the OVER clause with functions to compute
>   aggregated values such as moving averages, cumulative aggregates,
>   running totals, or a top N per group results.

Comment: Thanks - could you possibly give an example of how to use the `OVER` clause on either of my example tables to produce the example outputs?

Comment: analytic query functions are so often overlooked. this seems like a prime case for one..use a window to define the range that each record belongs to

Answer (score 1):

Well, some years ago with Oracle DB we did it the following way:

1. We had two tables: Sessions and Ranges. Ranges had foreign key that referenced Session.
2. When we needed to perform SQL, we created a new record in Sessions and several new records in Ranges that referred to that session.
3. Our SQL joined Ranges with filter by Session:

```
    select sum(t.Value), r.Name 
    from DataTable t 
    join Ranges r on (r.Session = ? and r.Start  t.MyDate)
    group by r.Name
```

1. After we got results we deleted that record from Sessions and records from Ranges where deleted by cascade.
2. We had daemon job that purged Sessions from junk records that were leaked in case of extraordinary situation (killed processes, etc).

This worked perfectly. Since that time Oracle added new SQL clauses, and maybe they could be used instead. But on other RDBMSes this is still a valid way.

Another approach is to create a number of functions such as GET_YEAR_BY_DATE or GET_QUARTER_BY_DATE or GET_WEEK_BY_DATE (they would return start date of corresponding 
period, for example, for any date return start date of year). And then group by them:

```
select sum(Value), GET_YEAR_BY_DATE(MyDate) from DataTable
group by GET_YEAR_BY_DATE(MyDate)
```

Answer (score 1):

My favorite case in this genre is where transactions must be grouped by fiscal quarter or fiscal year.  The fiscal quarter or fiscal year boundaries of various enterprises can border on the bizarre.

My favorite way to implement this is to create a separate table for the attributes of a date.  Let's call the table "Almanac".  One of the columns in this table is the fiscal quarter, and another one is the fiscal year.  The key to this table is of course the date.  Ten years worth of data fill up 3,650 rows, plus a few for leap years.  You then need a program that can populate this table from scratch.  All the enterprise calendar rules are built into this one program.

When you need to group transaction data by fiscal quarter, you just join with this table over date, and then group by fiscal quarter.

I figure this pattern could be extended to groupings by other kinds of ranges, but I've never done it myself.

Comment: PS: another use for the Almanac table is to have a Boolean column called "Holiday".

Comment: In general case holidays are country specific. You should have a separate table for that, with unique key by date + state/country.

Answer (score 1):

In your first example your intervals are regular so you can achieve the desired result simply by using functions. Below is an example that gets the data as you require it. The first query keeps the first column in date format (how I would preferably deal with it doing any formatting outside of SQL), the second does the string conversion for you.

```
DECLARE @OrderHistory TABLE (Date DATE, Quantity INT)
INSERT @OrderHistory VALUES 
    ('20120701', 2), ('20120702', 5), ('20120708', 1), ('20120710', 3), 
    ('20120714', 4), ('20120717', 2), ('20120728', 6)

SET DATEFIRST 7

SELECT  DATEADD(DAY, 1 - DATEPART(WEEKDAY, Date), Date) AS WeekStart,
        SUM(Quantity) AS Quantity
FROM    @OrderHistory
GROUP BY DATEADD(DAY, 1 - DATEPART(WEEKDAY, Date), Date)

SELECT  WeekStart,
        SUM(Quantity) AS Quantity
FROM    @OrderHistory
        CROSS APPLY 
        (   SELECT  CONVERT(VARCHAR(6), DATEADD(DAY, 1 - DATEPART(WEEKDAY, Date), Date), 6) + ' to ' + 
                    CONVERT(VARCHAR(6), DATEADD(DAY, 7 - DATEPART(WEEKDAY, Date), Date), 6) AS WeekStart
        ) ws
GROUP BY WeekStart
```

Something similar can be done for your age grouping using:

```
SELECT  CAST(FLOOR(Age / 10.0) * 10 AS INT)
```

However this fails for 30-39 because there is no data for this group.

My stance on the matter would be, if you are doing the query as a one off, using a temp table, cte or case statement should work just fine, this should also extend to reusing the same query on small sets of data.

If you are likely to reuse the group however, or you are referring to significant amounts of data then create a permanent table with the ranges defined and indices applied to any columns required. This is the basis of creating dimensions in OLAP.